# Android - Retrive particular line or lable from text file and display on a list View?

Tags: android, android-listview, text-files

I have a text file, and i was able to read the full content and display it on a view.

Sample file: http://pastebin.com/yCmpJfG0

But my requirement is I need to get particular data from the field names. 
Example, I need to retrieve `Name_1`, `address_1` and `Phone_1` from `"Label_1"` and then display on a separate `list view`. and then `label_2` values and so on.

Comment: Need solution for .txt file only, not JSON format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33096301/5315664 references this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to solve this problem, this is not an android problem. The following code maybe will be useful (put the text file into res\raw folder, example res\raw\test.txt):

(you can try a similar code in this [LINK](http://goo.gl/S2oSmT))

```
    final String PHONE = "PHONE";
    final String ADDRESS = "ADDRESS";
    final String NAME = "NAME";

    InputStream in_s = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
    byte[] b = "".getBytes();
    try {
        b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error!");

    }
    String[] words = (new String(b)).replace(":: label_", "").split("\\n");
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> h1 = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
    int groupNumber = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String str = words[i];
        if (!str.isEmpty()) {
            if (str.equals(String.valueOf(groupNumber))) {
                HashMap<String, String> h2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                h1.put(groupNumber, h2);
            } else {
                h1.get(groupNumber).put(PHONE, words[i]);
                h1.get(groupNumber).put(ADDRESS, words[++i]);
                h1.get(groupNumber).put(NAME, words[++i]);
                groupNumber++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(h1);
```

This code shows a hashmap:

```
{1={NAME=<PHONE_1>, ADDRESS=[ADDRESS_1], PHONE=[NAME_1]}, 3={NAME=<PHONE_3>, ADDRESS=[ADDRESS_3], PHONE=[NAME_3]}, 2={NAME=<PHONE_2>, ADDRESS=[ADDRESS_2], PHONE=[NAME_2]}}
```

You can get a value with:

```
h1.get(1).get(PHONE);//this returns de phone value from group 1
```

This code works only with your text file (but you can change for other structures):

```
:: label_1
[NAME_1]
[ADDRESS_1]
<PHONE_1>

:: label_2
[NAME_2]
[ADDRESS_2]
<PHONE_2>

:: label_3
[NAME_3]
[ADDRESS_3]
<PHONE_3>
```

(Edited)
Assuming that the text is http://pastebin.com/fPDm72fe, I changed a piece of code:

```
String[] words = (new String(b)).split("\\n");
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> h1 = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
    int groupNumber = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String str = words[i];

    if (!str.trim().isEmpty()) {
        if(str.contains("::")){
            HashMap<String, String> h2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            h1.put(groupNumber, h2);
        } else {
            h1.get(groupNumber).put(PHONE, words[i]);
            h1.get(groupNumber).put(ADDRESS, words[++i]);
            h1.get(groupNumber).put(NAME, words[++i]);
            groupNumber++;
        }
    }    
}
```

You can try his [here](http://goo.gl/SfGaQp)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
But in my case, we will not have the Label_1, Name_1, Address_1 and Phone_1. The txt document has a direct value without any labels. 

That is the reason I added different number for the label name. so each line has different names and address.

Comment: I have added a sample text structure below, it will make it clear. 

http://pastebin.com/fPDm72fe

Comment: @vishnupalanivelM Ok, for solve this problem, you must have a certain structure for get each value, as you say if each header will be ":: Carpenter", then the unique method for getting a group will be search the string "::". Is this correct? I need a pattern for determinate each group.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Thanks. I can get ":: " title value of all unique ids.

But I require the details of in-between data without hash-mapping. the data sometimes are also in the next line too. I Mean, on some case i have 5 lines, on other in have 8 lines of text. So I need all the lines below ":: " till next ":: "

Comment: The data are not in a proper format, So we require all data each line by line until ":: " occurs.
http://pastebin.com/ecQDCPx7

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JSON: (But who am I?)

```
[
    {
        "Name": "name_1",
        "Adress": "adress_1",
        "Phone": "phone_1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "name_2",
        "Adress": "adress_2",
        "Phone": "phone_2"
    },
    {
        "Name": "name_3",
        "Adress": "adress_3",
        "Phone": "phone_3"
    }
]
```

Now you can use JSONArray and JSONObject to retreive the items!

```
ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = oneObject.getString("Name");
            String adress = oneObject.getString("Adress");
            String phone = oneObject.getString("Phone");
            personList.add(new Person(name, adress, phone));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Oops
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you can use the persons in the list for the listView.

Comment: I'm sorry! Is this text file always in that format? Then you could use a BufferedReader and read each line, use the `:  :` as seperation?

Comment: Yes, Each set has staring ': :' in the first line. It means a new set of details is started.