# How to get particular line to line from text file and display array list in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, text-files

I have a text file, and i was able to read the full content and display it on a view.
Sample example format for text file :-

```
## userdetail 

   [William]
   [Bits]
   6th cross road, City house.
   Rio.
   <051-22345690>|<002-22345690>

## calldetails

    income 22.
    out going 24.
    missed 21.


## Lorempsum
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
 when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book 


## userot 
 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
```

...........
...........
...........

it like more 50 line

But my requirement is I need to get particular data from the field names.I can get "##  userot"  value of all unique ids. But I require the details of in-between data without hash-mapping. 
the data sometimes are also in the next line too. I Mean, on some case i have 5 lines, 
on other in have 10 lines of text. So I need all the lines below "## " till next "##" –

friend please give me solution for it ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the file line by line until you find `## userot` then reading lines until you find another line starting with `##` ?

Comment: This is ## unique one each and every ## its like header , but i need ## userot  paragraphs only in line by line ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below is find all the lines after '## userot' until the next ##

```
FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
InputStreamReader inputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputRead);

while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
    if(str.contains("##") && str.contains("userot"){
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if(str.contains("##"))
              break;
            else
              Log.d("TAG","output: " + str);
        }
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Friend in this code line , why should  have you will get two time in "file name" tell me  briefly..

Comment: i have error  for " in" filename ..  how to initialize filename friend, otherwise i use this  BufferReader for "reader.readLine "

Comment: Use anything you want, you just need to change "readline(filename)" to something that works, and then this code should work smoothly.

Comment: ok ... friend i change this readline(filename) again error will be occurs, one request  i need  run this method http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSU9TeFRyYU1xVUU   ...... sample page create and run this method

Comment: Ok, I edited this so you could run it just by changing the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, it may help you:-

```
String sAddr="";
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn=c.openFileInput(LOGS_TEXT_FILE);
            InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            int charRead;

            while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                // char to string conversion
                String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                sAddr +=readstring;
            }
            InputRead.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          String[]sAllAddrs = sAddr.split("\n"); // it would read the next line data and save it to a string.
          for(int i=0; i<sAllAddrs.length;i++){
                try {
                    //perform your logic to get those and write them...
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.storydata);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 8192);

    try {
        String line_1;
        while ((line_1 = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            while ((line_1 = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            if(line_1.contains("##") && line_1.contains("userot"))
            {
                while ((line_1 = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(line_1.contains("##"))
                        break;
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" +line_1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }


        }


        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

line by line reader text file ....  thanks for Hussain Alaidarous its work perfectly ....